# Oracle ADF : Making Image as Multi-Clickable

Tags: oracle, jsf-2.2, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

We are developing a web application using Oracle ADF. Our application has a page with the following image

[image: application image]

We need to implement Image Mapping functionality which is available in normal HTML. Means the above image should be multi-clickable. For example when user clicks **Business Value Health** part, I need to show some description and if user clicks **Operations Health** part, I need to show some other description.

How do I make this image multi-clickable in ADF?

Comment: Check this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661611/how-to-render-an-image-with-map-with-jsf-richfaces

Answer (score 0):

You won't have such feature directly from ADF, but you can decompose the big image into 13 smaller images where each image can have it's own link.

Of course, you then will need to assemble big image from css and that requires a bit of CSS knowledge.